# Get Gherkin Scenario failure line and message

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am Using Cucumber to write my scenarios. My aim is to get the error result and if possible the number of the line that broken the scenario and pass it as a variable which i will use later on.

I have searched far and wide and i came upon the below lines of code and implemented an Event Listener in a separate file.

```
public class TestListener implements ConcurrentEventListener {
    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::handleTestCaseFinished);
    }

private void handleTestCaseFinished(TestCaseFinished event) {
    TestCase testCase = event.getTestCase();
    Result result = event.getResult();
    Status status = result.getStatus();
    Throwable error = result.getError();
    String scenarioName = testCase.getName();
}
```

}

My aim is to get the result.getError() and store it in a variable when the scenario is failed but it is beyond my knowledge at this point on how to do it.

```
@After
public void nameCatcher(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    if (seleniumCore.driver != null) {
        seleniumCore.driver.quit();
    }
    if(scenario.isFailed()) {
        testRailAPItBean.setExecutionResultStatus(TestRailAPIConst.TEST_FAILED);
    } else if (scenario.getStatus().name().equals("PASSED")) {
         testRailAPItBean.setExecutionResultStatus(TestRailAPIConst.TEST_PASSED);
    }
    TestrailRestApi.updateTestCaseResulForTheLastActiveRun();
}
```

I tried to have the Listener in the class i am gonna use it but when i reference it it needs an event variable which when i set as below it gives me an error "Passing 'null' argument to parameter annotated as @NotNull"

```
EventPublisher eventPublisher = null;
    setEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
```

Also scenario.getError() gives me "Cannot resolve method 'getError' in 'Scenario'"

Below is my Gradle Configuration in case it is needed

```
    plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "master-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.13.0")
    testImplementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.13.0")
    implementation ("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.13.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching i found the solution below
We get the delegate class from the scenario. We are then making it accessible as by default the accessibility is set to false.

We then proceed to make a list off all the steps that have Failed.
Then we eliminate all the lines that I don't need and create a stringbuilder value to use depending on the needs

```
    public static void testCompletionHandler(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    
    
    Result failResult = null;
    
        //Get the delegate field from Scenario
        Field delegate = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
    
        //make delegate accessible since normally it is not
        delegate.setAccessible(true);
        TestCaseState testCaseState = (TestCaseState) delegate.get(scenario);
        
        Field testCaseField = testCaseState.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
        Field stepResults = testCaseState.getClass().getDeclaredField("stepResults");
    
        testCaseField.setAccessible(true);
        stepResults.setAccessible(true);

        List<Result> results = (List<Result>) stepResults.get(testCaseState);
        //Get the failed step line
        for (Result result : results) {
            if (result.getStatus().name().equalsIgnoreCase("FAILED")) {
                failResult = result;
            }
        }

        assert failResult != null;
//Create a stringbuilder to convert the stacktrace to viewable and printable values
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = failResult.getError().getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement element : stackTrace) {
               sb.append(element.toString());
               sb.append("\n");
        }
        String[] train = sb.toString().split("\n");
        sb.setLength(0);
//Get the final 3 stackTraceElements that usually contain the exact location of the error
        int i = train.length - 4;
        for (; i < train.length; i++) {
               sb.append(train[i]);
               sb.append("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).